# Postgresql error when creating new Database: role "ofbiz" does not exist

Tags: apache, postgresql, ofbiz

I am new to both Postgresql and Apache ofbiz. I am trying to connect postgresql to ofbiz but getting this error when trying to create new database.

Answer (score 1):

First, create three databases in postgresql: ofbiz, ofbizolap and ofbiztenant.  You also need to create an user that has table creating privileges in all three database. Next, some changes need to be made to /framework/entity/config/entityengine.xml. and /build.gradle.  See this detail instructions in the confluence (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/Setup+OFBiz+version+16.11.02+with+PostgreSQL+on+Windows).

Note: property for  jdbc-uri is "jdbc:postgresql://host ip:db port/db name".  db port is the port which postgresql is running.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created this role in postgresql ? If not, I think the easiest way is to open a terminal, take the postgresql default's user named "postgres" and create a role named "Ofbiz", "Akshay" or whatever you want.

On Ubuntu, you might try this (I don't know for other OS) :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL

Comment: I figured out the problem. It was same as you have mentioned(I had not created the desired role). After creating the role, it works perfectly.